# Expect command does not see stdout when executing with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, linux

I wrote a bash file with expect command, expecting some output and do actions based on that it works when I execute it in the terminal but when I execute it using exec in nodejs it does not work. I think the output of commands I run in bash file cannot be seen by expect

Comment: Can you post your code, which you are using in nodejs? so that its more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use, [shelljs Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs), for executing commands or shell scripts via nodejs.

```
 const shell = require('shelljs')

 shell.exec('./path_to_your_file')
```